# I just wanted to compile my script in pyinstaller and got some errors. How can I fix them?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I just wanted to compile my script, but I've got problem with pyinstaller.

```
106 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
106 INFO: Python: 3.6.7
106 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
108 INFO: wrote c:\Users\work\Desktop\Работа\py\buffer\buffer.spec
109 INFO: UPX is not available.
112 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['c:\\Users\\work\\Desktop\\Работа\\py\\buffer',
 'c:\\Users\\work\\Desktop\\Работа\\py\\buffer']
113 INFO: checking Analysis
113 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
114 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
117 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
119 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in walk_packages
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 127, in iter_modules
    for name, ispkg in iter_importer_modules(i, prefix):
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 146, in _iter_file_finder_modules
    import inspect
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\inspect.py", line 41, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in walk_packages
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 127, in iter_modules
    for name, ispkg in iter_importer_modules(i, prefix):
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 146, in _iter_file_finder_modules
    import inspect
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\inspect.py", line 41, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
3560 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3589 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
3957 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3964 INFO: Analyzing c:\Users\work\Desktop\Работа\py\buffer\buffer.py
5161 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
6488 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import distutils.core
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from distutils.dist import Distribution
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 9, in <module>
    import re
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 443, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 201, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1348, in run_script
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2417, in _safe_import_hook
    edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1438, in import_hook
    target_module, target_attr_names):
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1726, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    attr_name, submodule_name, package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2417, in _safe_import_hook
    edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1438, in import_hook
    target_module, target_attr_names):
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1726, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    attr_name, submodule_name, package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2028, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2813, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2417, in _safe_import_hook
    edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1438, in import_hook
    target_module, target_attr_names):
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1726, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    attr_name, submodule_name, package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1421, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2028, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2813, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1422, in import_hook
    target_module = self._load_tail(target_package, target_module_partname)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1635, in _load_tail
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 271, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1990, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2082, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2544, in _scan_code
    self._process_imports(module)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2743, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2221, in _safe_import_hook
    target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_attr)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1422, in import_hook
    target_module = self._load_tail(target_package, target_module_partname)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1635, in _load_tail
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 260, in _safe_import_module
    hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
  File "c:\users\work\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py", line 34, in pre_safe_import_module
    for real_module_name, six_module_name in real_to_six_module_name.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Hi @Roflin1337, please display your error logs in code format and provide further information so that people can help you :)

Comment: Please provide your script too.